Python3 importing enum from directory
I need to import enum class which sits in dir A from some other file which is in dir B.
So I have the following:
- enums
 -- __init__.py
 -- flavors.py
- setUp
 -- test.py

flavors.py
from enum import Enum, unique


@unique
class Flavor(Enum):
    VANILLA = "vanilia"
    CHOCOLATE = "chocolate"
    MINT = "mint"

In the test.py I just need to import this enum, but whatever way I chose getting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enums'

Please show the attempts you made.

I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:
For example, you wanna use the Enum (Flavor) in a new Enum you create in test.py.
In your test.py file, You can try something like:
from enums.flavors import Flavor


class TestEnum(Flavor):
    BROWN_CHOCOLATE = "brownchocolate"
    PEPPERMINT = "peppermint"

